# What is the interpretation of a lagged variable in panel regression? Why can it change the coeff. of another variable?

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model

I am refering to Woolridge Example 14.1. The example compares the change in scrap rates based on grants given out for worker training. The time periods are 1987, 1988 and 1989. The first grants were given out in 1988. Ten grants to different firms were given out in 1989.

Dummy variable are included for time trend effects. Now what I don't get, Woolridge states that:

*Finally, it is crucial to allow for the lagged effect in the model. If we omit grant-1, then we are
assuming that the effect of job training does not last into the next year. The estimate on grant when
we drop grant-1 is .082*

How can that be the case? Grant-1 basically measures the impact on productivity of firms that received a grant in 1988. Grant measures the impact a grant had that was given out in 1989 (to ten different firms). Aren't we then only looking at the change in productivity for firms that received the grant in 1989? How does our estimate change when we also look at how productivity evolved in firms that were given a grant a year earlier?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: You see a firm in multiple years, so the estimated effect is identified off the variation across time within each firm in trained workers. In 88 and 89, the firms that receives grants in that year for the first time have that year’s productivity changed. In 89, you also have some firms that had grants in 88 and also 89. They have have an even better productivity improvement in 89. You also have firms that got the grant in 88 but not 89. They are even more productive in 89 than 88, but not as productive a compared to if they got a second year of grants.

Comment: Thank you but that's exactly what I don't quite understand. The example states that ten different firms got the grant in 89. So there is no overlap of firms that received a grant in 88 and 89. This is were my confusion comes from.

Comment: You are right! But you don't need firms like that unless you want to estimate an interaction if grant and lagged grant. The -0.442 coefficient is the effect of having had a grant in 88 on 89 productivity. One potential mechanism is that the workers trained in 88 train those who did receive the training or it takes some time for them to fully apply the lessons.

Comment: In the data, 91 firms got (0 0 0) , 30 firms got (0 0 1 ) and 36 had (0 1 0 ).         36